# Visual Studio Mac: NUnit: why do I have red lightning bolt next to project name?

Tags: macos, visual-studio, nunit

I think I have Unit installed correctly in Visual Studio Mac.

I don't seem to be actually able to run tests because there's a red lightning bolt next to the project's name.

This is how it looks:

[image]

The test I'm trying to run is on the left, the Tests Browser panel is visible in the middle, and in the Solution Browser on the right you can see my project with the NUnit packages installed.

I can right-click on the TestCase method name and I see 'Run Test(s)' in the context menu, but running it doesn't actually produce any results, and as you can see the test itself doesn't even appear in the Tests Browser panel.

Instead I just get that darn red lightning bolt and I can't get it to go away no matter what.

[And even if this seems really similar to another question, please don't mark it a duplicate, because when I searched 'red lightning bolt' StackOverflow didn't come up with any answers for me. It seems to me that many other people will type in 'red lightning bolt' as their first attempt to find an answer for this, and it would be great if they could find one here.]

Comment: Is the project being shown your tests project or your system under test? I ask because it shows a very large number of references that have nothing to do with NUnit as well as references to nunit packages, which wouldn't normally be used in a test like the one you show. Also, some of the references appear to have errors noted in the display.

Comment: vstest (the framework loading unit test cases) is not very good at reporting issues of projects, so you see that miserable icon. Unless you share the whole code base somewhere, it is impossible for others to tell what's up.